# Positive lookahead to match '/' or end of string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to do a positive lookahead to match an object ID in a given URL, regardless of where that object ID is in the URL. The idea being to match until either a '/' or the end of the string.  Here are some sample strings (bold being the ID I want to match):

- /objects/**obj_asd-1234-special**
- /objects/**obj_xyz-15434**/members
- /objects/**obj_aasdfaeastd-15d44**/other/asdf

Using this: objects/obj_(.+?)(?=/) matches the latter two as they both have a trailing slash.  I read that the lookahead supports regex as the matching character, so I tried this objects/obj_(.+?)(?=(/|$)) to no avail.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

This regex matches either EOF or a certain character (i.e. /).

```
(?<=\/objects\/obj_)(.+?)(?=\/|$)
```

Here is a [demo](https://regexr.com/47fur).

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
/objects/(.*?)(/|$)
```

It simply does a non-greedy match between `/objects/` and either a slash or eof

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a positive lookahead:

```
/objects/([^/]+).*
```

And then, the first group will hold your id value.

Here's an example in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('/objects/([^/]+).*')

>>> p.match("/objects/obj_asd-1234-special").group(1)
'obj_asd-1234-special'
>>> p.match("/objects/obj_xyz-15434/members").group(1)
'obj_xyz-15434'
>>> p.match("/objects/obj_aasdfaeastd-15d44/other/asdf").group(1)
'obj_aasdfaeastd-15d44'
```